# What does target mean in Scikit's Linear Regression object?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am using Scikit to perform ordinary linear regression on some random datapoints. However, I am confused as to what they mean by `target values` in their [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) of the fit method.

I am setting `X` to be an array of datapoints of the shape 100 x 2 (two dimensional). What do I pass as input for the `y` argument?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this context, "target" is a [synonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_and_independent_variables#Statistics_synonyms) for "dependent variable", "response variable", "regressand", "measured variable", "responding variable", "explained variable", "outcome variable", "experimental variable", and "output variable." I.e. it's the thing your trying to predict.

Comment: I thought this might be the case - so I passed the second column of my data into the fit function, as `reg.fit(data[:,0], data[:,1])`, but I receive an error stating `tuple index out of range`. Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: @sdasdadas `data[:,0]` has the wrong shape, you need `data[:, :1]`. Every sample needs to be a row. (scikit-learn is really built for multivariate problems, so if you have a univariate problem you have to adapt a bit.)

Comment: Thanks - `data[:,:1]` doesn't quite work but just passing `data` as the `X` argument does. I believe I understand how this works, so thanks again!

Comment: @sdasdadas: if you pass `data`, then you'll get a multivariate regression model where the output is always equal to the second input variable. That's no use.

Comment: can we say it as "class" of some data?

Comment: +1 for the list, immediately made sense when I was able to relate it to what I already know about statistics

Answer (score 0):

**target** is synonym of:

> label, class, name of object

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html